# How do I create a Pivot table in Python for two categorical variables?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

My data looks smth like:

| Index | Job | Y | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Yes | 1 |
| 2 | B | No | 2 |
| 3 | A | No | 5 |
| 4 | A | No | 0 |
| 5 | B | Yes | 4 |

I want to summarize the data in the following format, with job in the row and Y in the column:

|  | Yes | No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 1 |

I have tried the following code:

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index =['job'], columns = ['y'], values = ['balance'], aggfunc ='count')
```

I am not able to run the pivot without using balance in the value parameter. How do I get the above result?

Comment: your code seems to work except for column name capitalization discrepancy; what's the error you're getting if any?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data = {'Index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
'job': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
'y': ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes'],
'Balance': [1, 2, 5, 0, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pivot = df.groupby(['job', 'y']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

print(pivot)
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do this, you will need to do [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) first, to group the data on Job and Y columns to get the count of yes/no using the below code:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Job', 'Y'], as_index=False).count()

  Job    Y  Balance
0   A   No        2
1   A  Yes        1
2   B   No        1
3   B  Yes        1
```

You can then use [`df2.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to pivot this grouped table into the desired format:

```
df2.pivot(index='Job', columns='Y', values='Balance')

Y    No  Yes
Job         
A     2    1
B     1    1
```